# How can I deserialize and map this correctly?

Tags: c#, json, dynamics-crm

I'm building a plugin for Dynamics CRM that consumes an API and this is my problem.
When I get this Json string I can do the mapping easily. And I can call it properly.

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 2,
  "title": "qui est esse",
  "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
}
```

My Code :

```
public string callRestAPI()
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            var response =(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            string content = string.Empty;
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    return content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception($"api data is {content}");
        }
```

..
Mapping

```
public class RootObject
        {
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string body { get; set; }
        }
```

..And now a sample of how I call it

```
string Consume = callRestAPI();
 var Accs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(Consume);
                        try
                        {
                            Entity createcontact = new Entity("contact");
                            createcontact["firstname"] = "Joe";
                            createcontact["lastname"] = Accs.title;
                            createcontact["emailaddress1"] = "Joe.doe@gmail.com";
```

But when I get this type of string I get confused by it and I can't seem to do the calling of it correctly. My code works when I have to get the data from an API that return the first string but when I change to the second API that produces the below string nothing work and I'm just left confused.

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
    "first_name": "Janet",
    "last_name": "Weaver",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please show how you de-serialize that string and what results you get?

Comment: Just added the code.

Comment: Do you get an Exception/Stacktrace? Can you debug and look into the Accs variable?

Comment: Is the same API returning different JSON structures ?

Comment: Json is the serialisation of an object. You seems to  have 2 different API sending you different object. The second method should be deserialise to it's own object. You should also rename RootObject class to a meanningfull name. It's the return type from the API. Simply view Api call as method call taking an object return an object just those are serialized in Json.

Comment: You can generate the second object definition like you did for the first Json reponse. either use VisualStudio special past option or Json2CSharp website.

Comment: @Kgabeci, did my answer help you resolve the issue? ping me if there's something else you would like to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first json snippet:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 2,
  "title": "qui est esse",
  "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
}
```

... maps correctly to `RootObject` class.

However, your second json represents *hierarchy*:

```
{
   "data": {
       "id": 2,
       "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
       "first_name": "Janet",
       "last_name": "Weaver",
       "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
   }
}
```

... there's the root object, then `data` object, so it can't be mapped to `RootObject` (so semantics-wise, it shouldn't be called "*Root*Object" anymore).

So you've got 2 options:

1. Just add a class that represents that hierarchy:

   ```
   public class Response
   {
       public RootObject data { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   ... and then:

   ```
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
   ```
2. Or, select the nested object json only:

   ```
   string dataJson = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("data").ToString();
   var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(dataJson);
   ```

Comment: Thanks I realized what I had to do as soon as I saw your post. I feel bad I didn't figure that out before.